# One or more Form Components in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting to work with reactJS. I have a little doubt, probably stupid, but i think always is better ask. Since I road the react's documentation, I know that we can create Components and Change their states. Now. I have two questions.

1. Is better make everything with components? I say without html with static files?
2. What can I do? Create one "Form Component" and change his state or create new forms and field forms or may create a new FormComponent for each Form that I need in an application?

About the first point:

In this moment I have two Form Components : 
Component **Login**

```
class Login extends React.Component{


    render(){
        return (
            <form action="#">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <InputControl id="oldPassword" name="oldPassword" placeholder="Contraseña anterior">
                        <InputControl className="form-control" placeholder="Usuario"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <ul className="list-unstyled lista-links">
                            <li>
                                <Link to={Rutas.cambioClave}>Olvido su contrase&ntilde;a</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <Link to={Rutas.registro}> Crear nueva Cuenta</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <BtnLink onClick={()=>this.iniciarSesion()} label="Iniciar Sesi&oacute;n"/>

            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

And Component **Registro**

```
class FormRegistro extends React.Component{


    registro(){

        console.log("llamada ajax para el registro");

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form action="#">
                    <InputControl id="user_name" className="form-control" name="user_name" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario"/>
                    <InputControl id="email" className="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Correo"/>
                    <InputControl id="password" className="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Clave"/>
                    <InputControl id="confirmacion_password" className="form-control"   name="confirmacion_password" placeholder="Confirme su Clave"/>

                </form>

                <BtnLink onClick={()=>this.registro()} label="Registrarse"/>
            </div>

        );
    }   
}
```

Both of them uses a Component name "inputControl" who create the diferents types of inputs.
But since in *React* everything can be a Component, I think my I can create only a "Form" component and change his state when i need a new form with differents inputs. In this case, Only a "Form Component" a change his state for make the "Login" form and change again for make "Register" form. But i don't know if this is a good idea or practice.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "without html with static files"? 2. Totally unclear.

Comment: Ok, I say For example, in my app. I have a first screen which show a login form and links for go to registration or password recovery. I only have the main html with "root" div and  I have an react class for each screen (no html files).

Comment: 1 -> Basically everything is a component in React. 2 -> Can you explain how you want the form to work exactly? What fields are there and what behavior do you want? Make a static html example an post it here.

Comment: I will change the question adding what I have.